# Strategy entry on strategy exit

Tags: pine-script

I want to ask if you are able to put strategy entry on your strategy exit. For example you buy EUR/USD, then it hits your Profit strategy exit and it would automatically open short position. The second question is if you can have two strategy entries. One would be normal one when some conditions are met and the second one will be on your strategy exit.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question seems to be very broad.

Comment: Why don't you use `strategy.order` - there you can sell two times as your position, so you go from the `long` right to `short` in one command. Suppose, it also answers your second question.